# Select all the columns from a table but group it with only few

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

May be this is a basic question but I’m unable solve this by myself, it will be greatly appreciated if someone can help me in achieving the following:

I want to get all the columns from a table but group it with only few. My query is as follows:

```
SELECT NATIONAL_ID,
         EMPLID,
         PLAN,
         CHECK_DT,
         PERIODS,
         SUM (SALARY),
         SUM (EE_CONT),
         SUM (ER_CONT),
         SUM (AL_HOURS)
    FROM DTL_TMP
   WHERE EMPLID = 'xxxxx'
GROUP BY NATIONAL_ID,
         EMPLID,
         PLAN,
         CHECK_DT,
         PERIODS;
```

If I add more columns to the above query it returns all the rows but I want only rows that are returned by the above query.

I did try few other options/examples like below:

```
SELECT OD.ProductID, OD.ProductName, CalQ.OrderQuantity
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ProductID, ProductName
        FROM OrderDetails) OD
    INNER JOIN (SELECT ProductID, OrderQuantity SUM(OrderQuantity) 
                FROM OrderDetails 
                GROUP BY ProductID) CalQ
    ON CalQ.ProductID = OD.ProductID
```

But it retrieves multiple rows because of the non-existence of keys in the table. Now, if I make any field as a key it gives unique constraint violation.

Please help. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you add more columns to the select list they either have to be aggregated, or added to the group-by clause as well. If you are grouping by them and get additional rows then their values are not unique, at least within the grouping you already had. So - which of those non-unique values would you want to show?

Comment: Hi Alex,

Thanks for the quick response. I want to show all the columns in the table but, group it with only those that are mentioned above.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  Let's say that there are two rows that have the same set of values for the NATIONAL_ID, EMPLID, PLAN, CHECK_DT, and PERIODS columns but different values for the other columns.  What values would you want to be returned?

Comment: What do you mean by 'group by' then - every column has to either be part of the grouping, or be aggregated (e.g. min or max). Maybe add some sample data and desired output to your question.

Comment: Alex & Justin,

May be my requirement isn't clear or cannot be achieved via SQL.

I have 33 columns in the table and depending on the 4 columns (NATIONAL_ID, EMPLID, PLAN, CHECK_DT,PERIODS) I have to sum the SALARY, EE_CONT, ER_CONT, AL_HOURS. 

As Alex said my question or requirement doesn't make sense because there are other Columns that are to be considered but, most of the rows have same data.

Thanks!

Comment: Can I accomplish the task through SQL?